# Will I experience problems making a java program on Windows computer but then running it on a linux vps?

Tags: java, linux, windows, cross-platform, vps

So I am currently working on designing a game that will be multiplayer and to prepare for this I have begun looking at hosting options.  Besides hosting from my house on a dedicated server, the best and cheapest option I found was the use of VPS, more specifically Dotblock.  Now dotblock has both linux based and windows based VPS but the windows one is a lot more expensive and so my question is whether or not I will run into problems if I code my server program in java on my Windows computer but then eventually host it on a linux based VPS?

As far as I know there should be no problems but if there will be, what are they, and if there are no problems what limitations will I have while coding?  I understand I cannot reference anything Windows specific but will things such as time and tracking the mouse using LWJGL should change?

Thank you in advance and I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: No. JVM works independent of OS, so unless you are using some OS related functions in your code, you are good to go!

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!  I thought that was how it worked but I thought it was better to be safe than sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall it's relatively straightforward- that's one of the advantages of using java over other languages. I will offer you this advice; make sure you handle file paths in an environment-agnostic way. I've seen more than one error log on linux complaining that it can't reach 'c:\some\weird\path'.